# Will Gooligan or Gooligan-like near-future variants be capable of targeting Marshmallow users?

Tags: malware, android, apt

Android malware called Gooligan has already surpassed it's infection points up to 1M+ in Android market which targets *Jellybean* & *Lollipop*. Seems it doesn't work for *Mashmallow* due to security measures or the software architecture as a whole. Not sure. Details are expressed [technically](http://blog.checkpoint.com/2015/07/10/adware-or-apt-snappea-downloader-an-android-malware-that-implements-12-different-exploits/) by CheckPoint Researchers.

Most of it looks like Adware campaign, but if ones looks closely - it's a three staged attack, first 1. infection 2. exploitation & 3. post exploitation

Gooligan does root the device. Not sure if this can be called as just yet another malware or an APT!?

I am curious if Gooligan variants can be made with these same mechanisms for *Marshmallow* & how possible it might be?